# How to reset Pinescript valuewhen() after conditions are met?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am trying to create a script that highlights when an SMMA crossover happens and a Williams Fractal is painted afterwards.

I am using valuewhen() to capture the crossover. When a fractal prints and the RSI is above/below 50, I use the stored valuewhen() to verify that the crossover conditions are met and can highlight that background.

The problem is, I have no idea how to reset valuewhen() after the conditions are met.

Screenshot provided shows the script running shorts in red and longs in blue. The white background bar is where crossover occurred and I would want only the red bar next to it highlighted ( after the Fractal printed ) which signals an entry.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my first time writing a Pinescript so apologies for any noob errors.

```
// @version=5
indicator(title = "3 SMMA Cross Strategy", shorttitle="3SMMA", overlay=true)

// smma
len1 = input.int(60, minval=1, title="Length")
src1 = input(close, title="Source")
_sma1 = ta.sma(src1, len1)
smma_21 = 0.0
smma_21 := na(smma_21[1]) ? _sma1 : (smma_21[1] * (len1 - 1) + src1) / len1

len2 = input.int(100, minval=1, title="Length")
src2 = input(close, title="Source")
_sma2 = ta.sma(src2, len2)
smma_50 = 0.0
smma_50 := na(smma_50[1]) ? _sma2 : (smma_50[1] * (len2 - 1) + src2) / len2

len3 = input.int(200, minval=1, title="Length")
src3 = input(close, title="Source")
_sma3 = ta.sma(src3, len3)
smma_200 = 0.0
smma_200 := na(smma_200[1]) ? _sma3 : (smma_200[1] * (len3 - 1) + src3) / len3

smma_cross_21_200 = ta.cross(smma_21,smma_200)
smma_cross_50_200 = ta.cross(smma_50,smma_200)

// rsi 
_rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

// williams fractals
n = input.int(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2)

dnFractal = (high[n-2] < high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n+1] < high[n]) and (high[n+2] < high[n])
upFractal = (low[n-2] > low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n+1] > low[n]) and (low[n+2] > low[n])

// begin conditionals
check_shorts = ta.valuewhen((smma_cross_21_200 or smma_cross_50_200) and ((smma_200 > smma_50 and smma_21) and ( smma_50 > smma_21 )), close, 1)
check_longs = ta.valuewhen((smma_cross_21_200 or smma_cross_50_200) and ((smma_200 < smma_50 and smma_21) and ( smma_50 < smma_21 )), close, 1)

TRANSP = 90

bgcolor( dnFractal and check_shorts and _rsi < 50 ? color.new(color.red, TRANSP) : na )
bgcolor( upFractal and check_longs and _rsi < 50 ? color.new(color.blue, TRANSP) : na )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_when(_cond, _update, _reset, _default)=>    // {
    varip _output                     = _default
    _output := _reset ? _default : _cond ? _update : _output
    _output
```

should  do it..